# XML over 64K on Oracle 10g to load

Tags: xml, oracle

I work on Oracle 10g
I have to load a big XML into an XMLTYPE column so as to extract easily the content of some TAGs.
The problem is that during the load of the XML I get

ORA-31167: XML nodes over 64K in size cannot be inserted

and I've read that on Oracle 10g it's non possible to load more than 64K for an XML. This would be terrible for me, because I suppose I should to load the big XML into a CLOB column but after how could I find the TAGs I'm interested to?
Moreover some TAG are repetead and I know the name of the TAG and its TAG-father and everything would be very simple if I could use XML functions.
Have you got some advice? Has someone developed any function for extract the part of the CLOB contained between  and  that would be the two TAGs containg what I have to use and so to convert it into a smaller XMLTYPE?

Thanks in advance!
Mark

Comment: you can convert a clob to xmltype

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround possible in 10g using PL/SQL, it is an internal limitation. XMLTYPE was built with a restriction of nodes < 64k. Either you upgrade to at least 11g or you apply a patchset for 10.2.0.3

**Bug 4766097  Unable to extract contents from XMLType after insert - ORA-31167**

**First way**

If you can't upgrade, at least you could apply the patchset to 10.2.0.3 where the issue was solved. 10g is a very very old version, so you will probably find yourself in a lot of problems and headaches, so you should consider to upgrade, the sooner the better.

**Second Way**

There is a possible workaround in 10g prior to 10.2.0.3, **but it is not guaranteed.**

1. Store the XML document as CLOB.
2. Read the text/value of the elements > 64k use Java DOM API

An example of the 2 is:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

import oracle.xml.parser.v2.*;

public class DOMSample  {
static public void main(String[] argv) {
try  {

System.out.println("XDK version is " + oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.getReleaseVersion());

// Build XML document with text > 64k
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("<DOC>");
for (int i=1; i<=96000; i++)
sb.append("*");
sb.append("</DOC>");
String clobData = sb.toString();
System.out.println ("length of input XML " + clobData.length());

// Get an instance of the parser
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();
parser.setErrorStream(System.err);
parser.showWarnings(true);

parser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(clobData.getBytes()));

// Obtain the document.
XMLDocument doc = parser.getDocument();

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
Node n;
for (int i=0; i<nl.getLength(); i++)  {
  n = nl.item(i);
  System.out.println("Element name " + n.getNodeName() );
  n = n.getFirstChild();
  if (n.getNodeType() == n.TEXT_NODE)  {
     String out_text = n.getNodeValue();
     System.out.println("Length of text in DOC tag " + out_text.length() );
  }
}//end for
System.out.println(" Done ");
parser.reset();
}//end try
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e.toString());
}
} // end main

} // end Class

> export CLASSPATH=.:$ORACLE_HOME/lib/xmlparserv2.jar

> javac DOMSample.java

> java DOMSample
XDK version is Oracle XML Developers Kit 10.2.0.2.0 - Production
length of input XML 96011
Element name DOC
Length of text in DOC tag 96000
Done
```